# Best way of writing an expression in an if construct

Tags: php

I have a question about something that I found among PHP best practises book that I read.

What is the best way to do the following test?

```
if("value" == $variable){}
```

and

```
if($variable == "value"){}
```

Comment: See:  [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/142162)

Answer (score 3):

It's preference, the first is known as a [Yoda conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/577926) which helps to prevent accidentally assigning a variable in an if statement and masking a logical bug, however, it's arguably harder to read (it reads like yoda is speaking it.)

Answer (score 2):

The only way in which the order of the comparison matters is that if you put `"value" === $value` you avoid an accidental assignment (i.e. `$value = "value"`).

You should check out [the `===` comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) if you're looking for different ways of writing conditions. In general it's a good practice to avoid type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are the same, but you should check $variable is set

```
if(isset($variable) && $variable == "value"){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same.

Some people prefer `if("value" == $variable)`, because if you make an error and write only one `=`, it will complain.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this `if("value" == $variable){}`, it will save from the mistake we generally do by using `=` in place of `==`