# Order of items in compare

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I was reading PHP's Array man and I saw this:

```
<?php
// fill an array with all items from a directory
$handle = opendir('.');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $files[] = $file;
}
closedir($handle); 
?>
```

In the readdir man page, it says "Correctly way of looping".

I'd like to know if there's a difference between `X !== false` and `false !== X`. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9177903/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/11181802/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7261117/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/10656419/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12939684/1409082 and certainly other questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do some experienced programmers write expressions this way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309089/why-do-some-experienced-programmers-write-expressions-this-way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no difference.  The reason you'll sometimes see `false == x` instead of `x == false` is that it helps prevent accidentally typing `x = false` which is permissible in an if or loop structure but is probably not what you want.  `false = x` is nonsensical, and will generate an error instead of silently assigning something.

Answer (score 1):

No it's the same

writing this

```
false !== X
```

is also known as "Yoda condition" :)
Very useful when you want to avoid unexpected assignments (using = instead of ==)